# Is there a benchmarking tool to make some tests on the 7nodes quorum-example running on vagrant?

Tags: quorum, benchmark

I set my quorum network using 7nodes quorum-example running on vagrant.
Now, I need a testing tool to evaluate my implementation (TPS, latency, ...).
I tried some tools but every time I have problems:

1. https://github.com/jpmorganchase/cakeshop/tree/v0.10.0-pre.1 (cannot
   support the raft consensus)
2. https://github.com/persistentsystems/gauge (could not connect to the
       vagrant VM)
3. https://github.com/blk-io/blk-explorer-free (it run
   very well, but it  is blockchain explorer only, I need benchmarking
   tool)

need any helpful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chainhammer is likely the tool you should use: https://gitlab.com/electronDLT/chainhammer

Answer (score 0):

The process of how to conduct benchmark is discussed here in the following blog-

https://hackernoon.com/quorum-stress-test-1-140-tps-792f39d0b43f

You can conduct your own benchmark test by referring it.